# Details of records already stored in Kafka

Tags: apache-kafka

In fact I'm seeking a way to get details of records stored in kafka brokers for operation usage.

I have tried the `Kafka-consumer-groups.sh` tool but it only shows info of specified consumer group and there is no details of the very single record or bunch of records that shows their state(s) such as "consumed or not" and "consumed time".

Actually my senario is that once in a while my consumer does not consume correctly when my producer has already sent successfully. So I have to make sure where goes wrong.

Is there any way I can get some informations of records like that?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: even getting the timestamps of the records when they are stored in broker will help a lot

Comment: I know it's easy to get those details through Java code or something like that but what I need is something like a command-line tool script like those shipped with kafka binary package

Answer (score 0):

You can get the timestamp and the key of messages you consume using the kafka-console-consumer as follows :

```
kafka-console-consumer --bootstrap-server brk:port --topic urTopic  --from-beginning  --property print.key=true --property print.timestamp=true
```

In the future, in case you want to know if something is possible using the CLI scripts, simply execute the script with the --help option and you'll have a good description of what is possible.

Best regards.

Comment: Thanks a lot! I did read roughly over the kafka-console-consumer.sh man-page but didn't see carefully about --property option. I'm gonna try it.